# Can I change where cards are placed at creation?

Tags: tableau-api

When I use Tableau and it creates a card, it is first placed on the right side. I would like it to be on the left side and having to move it every time is inconvenient. Is there a way for me to change the settings so that Tableau puts it on the left side initially for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no setting to change this behavior.